# React Grid - setState not triggering render in Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme

This is driving me nuts!  I have tried all those tricks to get this data to render using lifecycle methods to compare prop data to current state of the row data in my  component but it would seem that maybe React Grid with the row prop is not updating because I can see the console log of the rows with data in my console.  It has data but it's showing 'no data' in my table which means when my table rendered there must have been 'no data'.  Now if I make simple change to the component, hit save, its updates and boom i see 3 entries in the table.  Which oddly now there are 6 entries in my console in the array.

```
export default class Demo extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            columns: [
                { name: 'teamName', title: 'Team' },
                { name: 'profilePic', title: 'Avatar' },
                { name: 'score', title: 'Score' },
                { name: 'profileName', title: 'profileName' },
                { name: '', title: 'Rank' }
            ],
            rows: [],
            pageSizes: [5, 10, 15],
            currentPage: 0,
            loading: true,
            counter: 0
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getRows();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getRows();
    }

    getRows = () => {
        this.setState({
            rows: this.props.league
        });
    };

    //   static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    //     if (props.league.length !== state.rows.length) {
    //       return {
    //         rows: props.league
    //       };
    //     }
    //     return null;
    //   }


    // componentDidMount() {
    //     console.log("NP1::",this.props.league)
    //     this.setState({rows: this.props.league})
    //   }

    //   componentDidUpdate(nextProps, prevState) {
    //     if(nextProps.league!==prevState.rows){
    //       //Perform some operation here
    //       console.log("NP2::",this.props.league)
    //       this.setState({rows: this.props.league});
    //       this.classMethod();
    //   }
    // }


    // static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    //     if(nextProps.league!==prevState.rows){
    //         console.log("NP::",nextProps.league)
    //         return{
    //             rows: nextProps.league
    //         }

    //       return 
    //    }
    //    else return null;
    //  }

    //  componentDidUpdate(nextProps, prevState) {
    //     if(nextProps.league!==prevState.rows){
    //       //Perform some operation here
    //       console.log("NP2::",this.props.league)
    //       this.setState({rows: this.props.league});
    //       this.classMethod();
    //     }
    // }

    // componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    //     console.log("NP::",nextProps.league+"----"+this.props.league);
    //     if (nextProps.league !== this.props.league) {
    //         console.log("NP2::",nextProps.league)
    //         this.setState({rows: nextProps.league})
    //     }
    // }

    // componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    //     console.log("NP::", nextProps.league + "----" + this.state.rows);
    //     if (nextProps.league !== this.state.rows) {
    //         this.setState({ rows: nextProps.league })
    //     }
    // }

    render() {
        const { rows, columns } = this.state;
        console.log("STATEDATA::", this.state)
        return (
            <Paper>
                <Grid
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}

                >
                    <RowDetailState />
                    <Table
                        cellComponent={Cell}
                    />
                    <TableHeaderRow />
                    <TableRowDetail
                        contentComponent={RowDetail}
                    />
                </Grid>
                {/* <PagingPanel /> */}
            </Paper>
        );
    }
}
```

I've left in the commented code so you can see the LF methods I've played with.  Here is what the first render looks like with no data and the console log of of my state data that includes rows.

[image: dx-react-grid]

My initial state of rows is [] so we know setState happened.  Why is that not triggering a render in this component.  I saw some posts about this with Ag Grid but is there any known issues with the React grid and getting it to render properly?

As mentioned, in Vs code, if I just do a line return (or make any change) and save.  The component updates.  I will have 3 entries render and 6 in the console array as seen here.

[image: after change]

Adding this so you can see state an league props at same time.

[image: State and Props]

Here is the parent Component

```
class LeaguePage extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        loadLeague: PropTypes.func.isRequired,    
      }
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.loadLeague();
      }

    render() {
        console.log("LEAGUEPROPS::",this.props);
        return (
            <div className="g-row">
                <div className="g-col">
                <h1>LeaguePage</h1>
                {/* <LeagueTable {...this.props} /> */}
                <br />
                <br />
                <RgDetail {...this.props} rows={this.state.rows}  />
                <br />
                <br />
                {/* <RgTable /> */}
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    console.log("MYSTATE::",state)
    return {
        league: LeagueSelector(state),
    }
  }


const mapDispatchToProps = Object.assign(
    {},
    leagueActions
  );

  export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LeaguePage));
```

An the selector for league

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import _ from 'lodash';

var data = [];

export function getLeague(state) {
  if (state.league) {
    return state.league;
  }
}

function transform(UserRecord) {
  const outerObj = UserRecord[Object.keys(UserRecord)[0]];
  data.push(outerObj);
  return data
}

export function getSortedLeague(state) {
  if (state.length > 1) {
    state.map(x => transform(x));
    return data;
  }
  else
    return data;
}

//=====================================
//  MEMOIZED SELECTORS
//-------------------------------------

export const LeagueSelector = createSelector(
  getLeague,
  getSortedLeague
);
```

Comment: You’re only calling `getRows()` when the component is first mounted, so `state.rows` and `props.league` get out of sync. Try using `this.props.league` directly in your `<Grid ...>` element

Comment: I have tried that.  I get 'no data' when I use `<Grid rows={this.props.league} columns={columns}>`

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(this.props.league)` to your `render()` function and check that it actually contains data at the time of render?

Comment: I see you set the state from props.. why don't you just do it in the constructor? you get props there. it is the same props.

Comment: @MTCoster I added an updated pic for with the props.

Comment: @Ido Cohen.  I could try doing it in the constructor.  Is there some reason I would have more success there?

Comment: @Puerto It looks to me like `props` is an array, not an object with a `league` key

Comment: Yes.  It supposed to be array of objects.

Comment: @MTCoster I'm using a selector in the parent to derive a new bit of state called league.  'league' is an array of objects.  I just updated the pic so you can see all the props.  But you can see the prop that was passed called 'league' is in fact what this is.  So 'this.props.league' is legit I think.

Comment: Can you show us the bit of code where you’re passing `league`?

Comment: @MTCoster I added the parent component and the selector. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was lesson learned the hard way.  All this time I was just returning may payload in my reducer (not replacing state with new state) then in the selector (seen above) I was deriving a new bit of state from that.  Bad pattern or practice I guess you could say. I lost myself and tried to get to fancy with my use of selectors.

My old reducer looked like

```
const user = [{
    UID: {
      Key: {
      profileName: '',
      profilePic: '',
      score: 0,
      teamKeysTier1: '',
      teamKeysTier2: '',
      teamName: '',
      uid: ''
    }
    }
  }];  

export function leagueReducer(state = user, {payload, type}) {
    switch (type) {
        case LOAD_LEAGUE_SUCCESS:
        console.log("REDPAYLOAD::",payload)
        return payload;

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

I basically forget the basic principles of reducers where you should create new bits of state, your store updates and that will in turn tell the connected components you have new data.  This 'connected' wiring was not working in my case I believe because I was not creating/replace in my reducer.  So I basically took everything I was doing in my selector (seen above), moved it to my reducer and I'm creating a new bit piece of state using Object.Assign (I know it's a bit terse but for now I"m fine with terse)

Here is my new reducer now.

```
import { LOAD_LEAGUE_SUCCESS } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const user = [{
      profileName: 'FEKing',
      profilePic: '',
      score: 100,
      teamKeysTier1: '',
      teamKeysTier2: '',
      teamName: 'TheCreator',
      uid: ''
  }];  

export function leagueReducer(state = user, {payload, type}) {
    switch (type) {
        case LOAD_LEAGUE_SUCCESS:
        payload.map(x => {
        const outObj = x[Object.keys(x)[0]];
        state.push(outObj);
        })
        console.log("user::",state)
        return Object.assign([], state);

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Now my connected components update and I get my data loading in my table.  Basically because of `Object.assign([], state)` :)